# Customer Number Rounding

Tags: java, numbers, javafx

As my first project I am putting together a statistics program for my Cricket games.

The issue I have come across is in cricket there are 6 balls in an over with the bowling notation being "overs.ballnumber". For example if I have bowled 4 overs and have bowled 3 balls in the new over the notation would be 4.3

What I need to know is how would I set up a number that rounds to the next over once it has reached the 6th ball.

E.g. 4.6 overs should round up to 5

Comment: Post your attempt please, we need somewhere to begin

Comment: Do you always want to round up, or just in some circumstances

Comment: The issue is i don't even know where to start since it is in a SQLite data base and I am using the SUM command to add all the totals up. 

any point in the correct direction would be great

Comment: soon as it gets to 6 I want it to go to the next whole number.

Eg
0.1 , 0.2 , 0.3 , 0.4 , 0.5 , 1   -                                    
1.1 , 1.2 , 1.3 , 1.4 , 1.5 , 2

Comment: O! Why are you storing both the balls and overs together?

Comment: its just part of cricket notation, in the 1800's they never considered us doing this!

Comment: If you use 6 as the base of the number I think you will be able to find a solution. ex: if the base is 6 then the numbers are 0,1,2,3,4,5 but you need to find a way for number of overs since it may go more than 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program demonstrates how you can assess the decimal portion of a value;

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {



        double roundedUp=Math.ceil(4.1);

        System.out.println(shouldBeRoundedUp(2.2,0.5)); 
        System.out.println(shouldBeRoundedUp(2.7,0.5)); 

    }

    public static boolean shouldBeRoundedUp(double value, double roundIfAbove){
        double decimalPart=value%1; //this is the modulus operator, or remainder operator 
        if (decimalPart>roundIfAbove){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Richard, I'll have a play around and see what I get

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a Score class, if I understand correctly you want to be able to increase the ball number and when it gets to 6 it should actually reset to 0 and increase the overs. I also assume that at any time you can increase the overs and the ball number is reset to 0. The string representation of this object can be modified to include a '.' between the 2 values.

```
public class Score {
    int overs = 0;
    int ballNumber = 0;

    public void increaseBallNumber() {
        if (++ballNumber == 6) {
            ballNumber = 0;
            ++overs;
        }
    }
    public void increaseOvers() {
        ++overs;
        ballNumber = 0;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return overs + "." + ballNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is obviously the right way to do this; I think the OP is dealing with some legacy data